# Jquery - Animate div on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I'm applying a simple animation to a div when hovering an id. The div is not a child of the id. So when my cursor leaves the id the div hides itself. 
This is correct, but I require the div to stay visible unless my mouse leaves it.

You may have to test to see my issue. Link is below.

Heres my jQuery:

```
            $(function(){
                $('.has-children').hover(function(){
                    var the_handle = $(this).attr('id');
                    var the_sub_nav = '#' + the_handle + '-sub-nav';
                    $(the_sub_nav).stop().animate({height:'200px'},1000);
                },function(){
                    var the_handle = $(this).attr('id');
                    var the_sub_nav = '#' + the_handle + '-sub-nav';
                    $(the_sub_nav).stop().animate({height:'0px'},1000);
                });

           });
```

Here is a link to the issue:

http://tinyurl.com/c9yunhu

(I should mention I'm resticted to that HTML code. I'm using an e-commerce platform and thats the only way I can create sub-categories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple JSFiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/uPDXX/1/

Edit: Here a short version: http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/uPDXX/3/

EDIT 2:

Take a look now, is based on your current html... obviously I will never use a js like that. =) but maybe it will help you...

http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/uPDXX/5/

Comment: Thats brilliant thank you, however I did state above I can't change the HTML code, its the only way I can fake sub categories...

Comment: I updated my Fiddle with a shorter js version. You just need to use .find() and css to let it work. If you can't change HTML maybe you can change css?

Comment: Take a look at my last Edit now... is on your html base.

Comment: Legend, I edited a bit to get exactly what I needed but it works perfectly! Andrea Turri YOU THE MAN!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly; Just remove the second function of `hover()` to make the div stay visible on mouseout. Complete code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.has-children').hover(function(){
        var the_handle = $(this).attr('id');
        var the_sub_nav = '#' + the_handle + '-sub-nav';
        $(the_sub_nav).stop().animate({height:'200px'},1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I need the div to hide on mouseout. The issue is when I try to  hover over the visible div it disappears... which is what is should do because I'm not hovering over the trigger anymore. But I need it to stay.

Comment: I did not understand that from the first version of your question. But I see that @Andrea Turri has made a nice solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the submenu container to the hover function, that way it will stay open while hovering over the menu item or the entire submenu.

```
$('.has-children, #submenu-ID').hover(function(){
```

Comment: Sorry I mentioned above I can't change the HTML structure, I've made an edit to my question to explain it better, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.has-children').on('hover', function(){
        var the_sub_nav = '#' + this.id + '-sub-nav';
        $(the_sub_nav).stop().animate({height:'200px'},1000);
    });
```